# How to configure IdentityServer4 Client for production behind a Reverse Proxy to address "Correlation failed. Unknown location" Error

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, identityserver4, correlation, production-environment

IdentityServer4 client through an IIS reverse proxy server getting “Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location”.

We have a .NET Core MVC application that authenticates with our Identity server 4 application. This is working well.

However we need to deploy this into an environment where the application server and the Identity server have to be accessed through a reverse proxy server.

In our client we change the OIDC Host of the Authority option to the reverse proxy server of our Identity server.

In Identity server we change the Host of the redirect Uri for this client to point to the reverse proxy for our client.

We have configured the client to pass the redirect Uri with the hostname of the clients reverse proxy server.

With this configuration when an unauthorized user access the client, the user is redirected to login on the Identity server.

The login is successful but the user gets the following error when returning to the client application: “Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location”.

However the use has been successfully authenticated and can access the client application.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
               {
                   options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                   options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("Uris").GetSection("IdentityServer").Value;
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   options.ClientId = "mvc";
                   options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                   options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                   options.Scope.Add("api1");
                   options.Scope.Add("openid");
                   options.Scope.Add("profile");
                   options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                   options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");
                  options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                   {
                       n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri =  Configuration.GetSection("Uris").GetSection("RedirectUri").Value;
                       await Task.FromResult(0);

                   };
```

**Error return in browser:**

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Correlation failed.

Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()

**Error Logging Information:**

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
      '.AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.pz2cS4-GHvVSgHgHOJQQTWa8dL_CDKjEBAGqA4Sg-RY' cookie not found.

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: I know where the "correlation failed" came from (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4fa5a228cfeb52926b30a2741b99112a64454b36/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L569), but did you configure any events that might have logged "Unknown location"?

Comment: @Randy, The post has been updated to include returned and logged error information. Do you have any suggestions or comments on the cause  "correlation failed" error or  how to address it.

Comment: Just updated with an answer to give a more in-depth explanation

Answer (score 3):

When '.AddOpenIdConnect' is called, an OpenIdConnectHandler gets registered through ASP.NET Core's dependency injection system and will get invoked with the options that you configure in the lambda.

This [OpenIdConnectHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4fa5a228cfeb52926b30a2741b99112a64454b36/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs) inherits from the [RemoteAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d8381656429addead2e5eb22ba1356abfb419d86/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs) which is where the method to [generate](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d8381656429addead2e5eb22ba1356abfb419d86/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L189) and [validate](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d8381656429addead2e5eb22ba1356abfb419d86/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L209) correlation ids lives. A correlation id is a random string that's set as the name of a cookie, and is set and verified on your browser to ensure you are using the same user-agent that initiated the login.

When the correlation cookie is set but not received, the [OpenIdConnectHandler will fail the request](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4fa5a228cfeb52926b30a2741b99112a64454b36/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L569). This failed request ultimately gets handled by the [RemoteAuthenticationHandler calling the 'Events.RemoteFailed' delegate on the OpenIdConnectOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d8381656429addead2e5eb22ba1356abfb419d86/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L89) (the RemoteAuthenticationHandler knows about the events because the OpenIdConnectOptions is actually a derived class of RemoteAuthenticationOptions).

To handle this authentication failure more gracefully, you can find a way to identify this failure within the OpenIdConnectOptions' and potentially show a session expired page, or find a way to automatically re-authenticate.

**TLDR**: ASP.NET Core sets a correlation cookie with a fairly short expiration time that fails the authentication if too much time is taken between the redirect to login and the code exchange. To handle it gracefully you can set the 'RemoteFailure' on the option's event property.